# Python set memebership test

Tags: python, set, cpython, membership

In an algorithmics course our teacher covered "virtual initialization" where you allocate memory for an operation, but don't initialize all the values since the problem space might be too large compared to the values that actually need to be calculated (for example a dictionary or set), which wastes a lot of time for setting a default value. The basic principle is to have two arrays that point to each other (index each other) and keep track of how many variables have been assigned. let's say we have an array a and we want to find if a[i] contains a valid value, we can use array b as an index to a like so:
[image]

I had a look at the python time complexity table at https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity and it mentions that a set membership test in the worst case can be of O(n). I'm not sure where to find the exact implementation of the set function but after a bit of googling, most people mention that it uses a hash table. My main questions are:

1. How can a hash table be used to check if a value is valid or not? We can hash every value and read the result, but that doesn't mean the output isn't garbage (we can be reading whatever was written to that address when malloc was called).
2. virtual initialization completely avoids the problem with collisions in a hash table, so why is it not a better solution than using a hash table?

Comment: I think you're confused about what this is about -- this is part of the implementation of the hash table, not something you use instead of a hash table.

Comment: If it does actually use a hash table, "in the worst case" is if all values have the same hash. Best case is O(1)

Comment: Who said anything about using a hash table to check if a value is valid? All you can do with a hash table is check if some value is in the  hash table or not.

Comment: And *for what* would virtual initialization be a better solution than a hash table?

Comment: @Esther I see you angry typing in the comments lol. Your second comment is exactly my question: HOW do you use a hash table to search for membership tests? you run a value through a hash function to get an index in O(1), but you can run ANY value through the hash function, so the result might be garbage (value not calculated).

A lot of applications need to have a fast membership test, for example, memoization of recursive call values or even set membership itself. A code example would be: "if k in a". HOW do you use a hash table to get the result of this memebership test?

Comment: @Barmar can you explain more? again I'm not sure how this is part of the hash table implementation. A link to the source code or explanation of how a hash table can be used to test for membership would be nice.

Comment: *HOW do you use a hash table to search for membership tests?*  You hash the value.  You do a linear search of the item(s) at that hash to find the desired key.  Assuming you have a good has function, that's usually going to be 0 or 1 comparisons.

Comment: Many implementations of hash tables have a linked list or other data structure at each "endpoint" for a hash. So Step 1: you hash the value, so you can find where in the hash table to look. Step 2: If there is only 1 value in the hash table that corresponds to that hash, you check if the value you have and the hash table value are equal (using whatever method of checking equality you desire). Step 3: if there is more than one value in the hash table with the same hash, you check all of them against your value one-by-one until you get to one that's equal, or don't.

Comment: The main point is that *just* finding a matching hash isn't enough to know that it's in the table, afterwards you *also* have to compare against the *original value* in the hash table in order to see if they are equal. Hash tables store data as key-value pairs, with the key being the hash and the value being whatever data is being stored.

Comment: I think you're still missing the point, we want to avoid initializing all the values. What you mention requires initializing all of the values to be a null pointer or empty linked list etc. I.e: you can't do table = malloc (n) and then check the hash of v in the table to check for membership, because you will get a value that was stored in the memory when you allocated memory.

Comment: @Esther since this is tagged with CPython (for some reason that isn't evident to me by the content of the question), I suppose it is important to note that CPython uses open-addressing, not seperate-chaining

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga interesting to know, although it doesn't change the bottom line as I understand, which is that a matching hash doesn't mean the item is a member of the set

Comment: @Esther if the values are initialized, then it does mean membership is true. I haven't managed to run through the source code you linked to the source code yet, but the use of "dummy values"  (-1) certainly suggests the entire table is initialized to some value (none, null, etc).

Comment: @OM222O no, it could have been initialized with a *different* value that has the *same* hash.

Comment: I was assuming a case with no collisions. but yes, you will need to perform collision checking as well. Bloom filters with multiple hash functions or similar can be used to guarantee that collisions are less than p% in big data systems, but that's subject for a different topic.

Comment: @OM222O you were asking about the default cpython implementation. Of course there are implementations that are better or worse for specific situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you implement a hash table using an array, you need a flag in each entry to indicate whether it's currently in use. This is needed to deal with hash function collisions -- if two values have the same hash code, you can't put them both in the same element of the array.

This means that when you allocate the array, you have to go through it, initializing all these flags. And you have to do this again whenever you grow the hash table.

"Virtual initialization" avoids this. The algorithm you pasted is used to tell whether an `a[k]` is in use. It uses a second array `b` that contains indexes into `a`. When inserting an element, `a[k].p` contains an index `j` in `b`, and `b[j]` contains `k`. If these two match, and also `j` is lower than the limit of all indexes, you know that the array element is in use.

To clear an entry, you simply set `a[k].p = 0`, since all valid entries have `p` between `1` and `n`.

This is an example of a time-space tradeoff in algorithm design. To avoid the time spent initializing the array, we allocate a second array. If you have lots of available memory, this can be an acceptable tradeoff.

Comment: How would you remove items from a set if you were using virtual initialization?

Comment: I think this will be foolproof because we know we have written to the first n elements of b, meaning those are correct indices. if some pointer from a to b (a[k].p) happens to point to the first n elements of b, but b[j] doesn't point to a, then we know that is an invalid value.

Comment: @KellyBundy Couldn't a random `j` be between 1 and n?

Comment: yes, but if it was then `b[j]` would not match the index you're looking at in `a`. Because you know `b[j]` was initialized if it's less than or equal to `n`

Comment: @Esther You can set `a[k].p` to `0`.

Comment: it can. let's say a[19].p is 2 and n is 10 (j between 0 and n). We check b[2] which we have written to, but find 12, not 19, meaning a[19] is invalid.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but if it's not valid, then `j` doesn't point back to it (i.e., the `b[j] == k` would detect that).

Comment: @OM222O But what if `b[2]` just by chance happens to contain `19`?

Comment: @Esther you don't delete items from a set in the use cases where this structure helps. It's usually used to cache values of previous computations in a large problem, which you really don't want to delete.

Comment: if 2 < n, then we already initialized b[2]. You initialize values in b in order.

Comment: @OM222O that was kind of my point, and why it likely isn't used for regular sets.

Comment: @Barmar it can't! you have written to the first n indices of b explicitly, overwriting any value that happened to be there. that is also the reason for returning false if j>n because that is the region that contains garbage values

Comment: Now I understand. I've removed my last paragraph, I didn't think that through completely.

Comment: If you check the [cpython source for sets](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/setobject.c), it has explicit "dummy" values for unfilled spaces in a set.

Comment: thanks, everyone for the comments, I think I understand it now. That actually gives me a few ideas on optimizing my old codes that used large lookup tables.

Comment: Instead of setting `a[k].p = 0`, it might be better to use its corresponding and now obsolete `b`-entry for the one that's at `b[n]`, i.e., move that one to the lower `b`-entry and decrease `n`. Otherwise if you have a lot of insertions and deletions, you're increasing `n` further and further. If `b` can grow and shrink (like a Python `list`), then that's wasteful and reusing obsolete `b`-entries would save memory.

Comment: @KellyBundy thanks! I was just trying to think of a more efficient way of deleting entries that wouldn't waste memory in b...

Comment: @KellyBundy This whole thing is a time-space tradeoff, and assumes memory is cheap.

Comment: And if `b` has fixed size, you'd *really* better do it that way, otherwise you might reach its end and can't (re-)insert values just because `b` contains a lot of obsolete entries.

Comment: @Esther [Demo](https://tio.run/##nVLLasMwELzrKxZ6sVNaUtpDKfGtl17yAyYUJdqkipWVkdeB9OdTPew4LiSkFdhmx9qZ0Y7qA39Zen6t3fG4dnYHTpLyH72rreNY@WeDQsyhgKcpTCbwAnAHRu80C/LgVOz9uzxtzeY5rK2DT9AEPbIIPR23kixFfWMPW2j0rjWSUSxv7GlJk2Ytjf5GleSEwjVUeMj20rSYvwnwyyG3jiBCacfKEktNzWhb5WWH1ghtPVSX1eKcZgqzwv@YAYG3CMtyu4DCdyZmT4qOR7wbY5fSAMVCXxAfBC552XsfHk2nCECdgNSwLCkUVSwI7n2IyZBCg4xXDZHl/5oaDYjgIch2rHFEA0@aU/R5wuoyoAHedtNjdJKtyzoDIfeodp79wHltmGEdNBrV576yzuGKvViDnOXi150Kdx4CeWS4g48YZH@Xh6knOwWc38905PPkI9IpPkqlergjf4@hgPwD/SjHEb3SzUq6QcJh05r@nMNEc1E7TZwZpKxrHWGp7QT1LEWvkx@PPw) for fun.